# Перенос строк в файле

Tags: c++

Суть быдлокода: если длина строки больше 80 символов то остальные слова из этой строки переносятся на новую строку.

Проблема в том, что в если файле больше одной строки то программа работает только с 1-й строкой столько раз, сколько есть строк всего.

```
string s,res,out;
stringstream tmp;

ifstream file("LAB5_8.txt");



while (true) {

    getline(file,s);
    tmp << s;


    while (tmp >> s)
    {
        if(res.length()+s.length()<=80) {res += s+' '; continue;}
        else out+=s+' ';
    }


    cout << res+'\n' << endl;
    cout << out+'\n' << endl;


    if (file.eof()) break;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А вы не тащите за собой все из предыдущих итераций.
Внесите

```
string s,res,out;
stringstream tmp;
```

после `while(true)`.

Всякие мелочи типа лишних пустых строк, думаю, обработаете самостоятельно?

Comment: Спасибо большое. Провтыкал что переменные не пересоздаюся при новой итерации)

Comment: @Ski, если ответ верен, то отметь ответь как верный, нажав зеленую галочку для закрытия вопроса